Finding files responsible for heap out of memory
I got this error:

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

I understand this is because I have some recursive types in typescript, but I don't know the file they're in. When I opened the files, they showed in VS code as errors and were marked. After I closed the file, there is no more error and I can't find the file.
Running tsc watch doesn't help, since this throws the memory error. Is there a way to run a full "scan project for problems" in VS code? I tried adding
"typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics": true, to settings but no luck.

Have you tried pouring over the TS server logs?

It seems like this will only show logs in vs code ts, so won’t actually run new scan. Am I missing smth?

Ok, it's enough to restart ts server (f1) and open the problems tab. It shows all issues, but it takes a while. Make sure you're in a ts file when restarting. Otherwise there is no restart option
